# i want to sort all dates in xslt of an xml

Tags: xml, xslt

this is the XSLT code to transform the xml document provided below. Please correct me where i have coded wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="segment/Dates">
       <xsl:for-each select="date">
           <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
               <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
               </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="date.xslt"?>
<segment>
    <Dates>
        <date> 2019-12-01 </date>
        <date> 2019-09-09 </date>
        <date> 2019-12-10 </date>
        <date> 2019-11-05 </date>
        <date> 2019-04-05 </date>
        <date> 2018-05-04 </date>
        <date> 2018-07-06 </date>
        <date> 2018-09-06 </date>
    </Dates>
</segment>
```

"and this is the xml file below"

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question.

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD 
2018-05-04
2018-07-06
2018-09-06 
2019-04-05
2019-09-09
2019-11-05
2019-12-01
2019-12-10

Comment: i want to sort like this in descending order

Comment: Please add the expected output (as code) **to your question**.

Comment: 2018-05-04

2018-07-06

2018-09-06
 
2019-04-05

2019-09-09

2019-11-05

2019-12-01

2019-12-10 want to sort like this in ascending order @michael.hor257k

Comment: Remove if condition..

Comment: @SadikSiddiqui Is any specific reason you use `position() = 1`?

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncntCSw

Comment: @Amrendra Kumar Thanks Dear

Comment: by the way i also traced the problem is where i have added position()=1, which is not required, i got my desired answer by removing =1

Comment: Removing `=1` makes the expression `position()`. This always evaluates to `TRUE`, because counting starts at 1, therefore making the `xsl:if` superfluous.

Comment: @zx485 above code sorted the dates and have got my answer but now i want to learn how to sort if we have all dates not in standardised format,if it given like 10/12/2019-06:30 (10th Dec 2019-time)

Comment: @Amrendra thanks for yesterday, above code sorted the dates and i have got my answer but now i want to learn how to sort if we have all dates not in standardised format,if it given like 10/12/2019-06:30 (10th Dec 2019-time)

Comment: Post a new question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k ok